# On linux, how to wrap text around the output of a command and save it to a file?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, terminal, browserify

`browserify my_file.js` returns a stream with the result of the conversion of my_file to browser. Is there a way to wrap "" readers around that output? For example: `echo "<html>" > browserify my_file.js > "</html>" > bundle.js` - or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
(echo "<html>"  
 $browserify my_file.js  
echo "</html>" ) > bundle.js
```

The `$browerify` seems to error in your example, like a command with a '$' accidentally prepended to it.  If so, change it by removing the leading $.

```
 (echo "<html>"  
    browserify my_file.js  
    echo "</html>" ) > bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try:
`echo "<html>$(browserify my_file.js)</html>" > bundle.js`

If you want extra carriage returns try:
`echo -e "<html>\n$(browserify my_file.js)\n</html>" > bundle.js`